# Add and update var time to realtime Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

---

Hello, I'm still a beginner in firebase, honestly I'm a bit confused hehehe, btw I want to add a time variable to realtime firebase and it will be updated every time the data changes.

Btw this is my code, I don't know what's next.

Thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGFX3.png)

```js
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
      authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      storageBucket: "xxxx",
      messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
      appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      measurementId: "xxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  

function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours());
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
  var times = h + ":" + m;


var database = firebase.database();

database.ref('Time').set({
        Recent: times
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: None of this code interacts with the database yet. Did you try anything for that? If not, this is probably a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours());
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
  var time = h + ":" + m; database.ref('Time').set({
            Recent: Time
        });
    }

Comment: Please add the relevant code in your question itself, instead of in a comment, so that you can mark it up to be readable. You can click the `edit` link under your question to make such changes.

Comment: Sorry , done .

Comment: The `Times` in `Recent: Times` is not defined anywhere. You've defined `times` above, but case matters here. So you'll probably want `Recent: times`.

Comment: thank you very much, is my script correct? 